# How to separate a timeline into multiple actions?

Tags: animation, nla-editor, timeline, actions, gltf

Blender is my bread and butter but there's a darkside within it I have 0 understanding of.

I've no idea how NLA and action editor work. I've an animation where you have 230 frames and a character shuffling cups, all of the movements are included in the single action/timeline.

How can I select certain keyframes and split them into multiple actions?

Also a thing that was disturbing my sleep is how do you export the actions properly if you have multiple animated objects (say the armature and the cup are keyframed separately), what's the proper way of creating / exporting actions for multiple objects?

The goal is to have multiple actions with different timelines and export it as glTF

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I guess you could cut the action in the NLA but perhaps the simplest way is to create several actions in the Dopesheet > Action Editor mode, then play with them in the NLA.

Comment: ooh didn't know you could cut actions, that's nice. But how would you create multiple actions if you already have the animation? 

Oh an any tips on dealing with multiple objects? How would you work out actions on different application (say Unreal or Unity) if you have multiple ones for each object? I'm a bit confused with this.

Comment: you need to switch the Dopesheet to Action Editor, then duplicate actions, edit them, copy-paste keyframes from an action to another, etc... a bit long to explain on this forum   ;)   then once you have all you actions, put them in the NLA and move them etc...

Comment: I tried avoiding that, there seems to be ways to split NLA strips but only on their midpoint which is weird.

Comment: in the right panel of the NLA (press N) you might be able to play with start and end of the clip, I need to check that

Comment: Animations tab > Action Clip > Action Extents I guess

Comment: So I can duplicate the NLA strips and offset them basically. This is a cool solution but I still need to figure out how all of this exports and how it works with multiple objects. Thank you so much!